# How to match only quotes around word that has only numbers in it?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

How can I match quotes around number:
Here is what I have:

```
"Austria","AU","ULO1","185","34","4dera"
```

Here is what I need:

```
"Austria","AU","ULO1",185,34,"4dera"
```

This is the closest I did:`\"(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\"`,
but the problem with that is that it also matches words that start with number and I can not put `+`,`*`or`.` in Look-behind or Look-ahead. I am trying to change .csv file with 1400 rows like this. I can replace it with Notepad++ because it supports regex or with python script.

Comment: You need to give more context. What is this data - is it a list of strings, or what? Where is it coming from?

Comment: is this a csv file?

Comment: yes this is csv file

Comment: I guess `isdigit()` would be useful to check if a given string consists of only number characters, but if you still want a regex then `^\"\d+\"$` would work I guess

Comment: `\"\d+\"` I believe this is what you want

Comment: No need for regex here at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Notepad++

search for: `\"(\d+)\"`
replace with: `\1`

Comment: Thank you champion!! This is exactly what i was looking for. I didn't want to write code, if there was an option not to.

Answer (score 5):

```
list1 = ["Austria","AU","ULO1","185","34","4dera"]

list2 = []

for item in list1:    
    try:
        list2.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        list2.append(item)
```

should return `strings` for strings and `int`'s for your numbers in `list2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
s = '"Austria","AU","ULO1","185","34","4dera"'
print(re.sub(r'"(\d+)"',r'\1',s))
```

Match every number enclosed in `"` and replace it with the number without the `"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.isdigit()`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print([int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in row])
```

**Output:**

```
['Austria', 'AU', 'ULO1', 185, 34, '4dera']
```